# How to place a recyclerview inside a scroll view?

Tags: android-scrollview, android-recyclerview

My View has a scroll view, Long enough, and at the bottom, i'm planning to show a comments section, which would basically be a recycler view. Dont know if this is right.

I've created a recycler view and everything as for a normal recycler view, but i'm not able to scroll the items in recycler view.

Please help me out..

Edit: 
Found a solution: example link in comment

Comment: I am facing same problem. I have created one screen with root view as ScrollView and having recycler view as it's child. I am able to scroll in scroll view but I am unable to scroll in recycler view smoothly.

Comment: @gauri: You say you are not able to scroll smoothly, but in my case i am unable to scroll at all.

Comment: I referred this link and did same as specified http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2014/01/handle-scrolling-of-scrollable-controls.html <br/> But still it's not working.

Comment: @gauri: as per your link, you need to make some modifications. check out this example here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ps3csfziohzsep/dbflowtest.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: My issue was items in my recycler view were clickable so clicked item was getting focus instead of recycler view because of which I was unable to scroll.

Comment: The recyclerview will scroll smoothly if you override the GridLayoutManager and tell it that it cannot scroll vertically. Create customGridLayoutManager and override this method:     @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically () {
        return false;
    }

Comment: @Mayur the dropbox link you referred is not working..